# How to read a query string in PHP for the purposes of location redirect?

Tags: php, redirect, curl

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$url=$header("Location: " . 'http://excample.com/'.$id'/direct/18/');
```

Please tell me how can I access for redirect curl.

Comment: change $header to header

Comment: It's worth casting that value thus: `$id = (int) $_GET['id'];`, otherwise the code may contain other headers added by a malicious user.

Comment: Bro I paste the full code in the comment please check scroll down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<?php

function get_final_url( $url, $timeout = 5 )
{
    $url = str_replace( "&amp;", "&", urldecode(trim($url)) );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );

    if ($response['http_code'] == 301 || $response['http_code'] == 302)
    {
        ini_set("user_agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");
        $headers = get_headers($response['url']);

        $location = "";
        foreach( $headers as $value )
        {
            if ( substr( strtolower($value), 0, 9 ) == "location:" )
                return get_final_url( trim( substr( $value, 9, strlen($value) ) ) );
        }
    }

    if
    (
        preg_match("/window\.location\.replace\('(.*)'\)/i", $content, $value) ||
        preg_match("/window\.location\=\"(.*)\"/i", $content, $value)
    )
    {
        return get_final_url ( $value[1] );
    }
    else
    {
        return $response['url'];
    }
}

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $url = 'http://excample.com/'.$id.'/direct/18/';
    echo get_final_url($url);
?>
```

Comment: this code not show redirect url but this code redirect and play video in new tab

Comment: @SyedAliRazaNaqvi you just want to see redirect URL?

Comment: check this link of your code hassan this code redirect on video but i want to show reidrect code on page

Comment: Work Nice But code give first redirect code of ytapi.com i need final redirection code http://r13---sn-vgqs7n7d.de2.ytapi.com/videoplayback? what is final redirection code see this http://r13---xx-xxxx.doc.google.com/videoplayback?

Comment: @SyedAliRazaNaqvi what do you want exactly?

Comment: I need final redirect code of doc.google.com look please visit this link copy on address bar http://ytapi.com/api/4FGLqe-5bgU/direct/18/ now this link redirect to doc.google.com i want to access this redirect code on page show as text

Comment: @SyedAliRazaNaqvi I got your point now. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks its Great Work

Comment: @SyedAliRazaNaqvi please accept my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: @SyedAliRazaNaqvi there is `tick mark` in top left side of my answer. Please click on it to accept my answer.

Comment: bro if i want to show 3 result on one id only change tag of 22 18 and 5 how can i do

Comment: Please visit this link bro if you creat this this is not impossible for you http://server1.yt-api.com/vimotube.php?id=5lf9GWCQcMA please visit only change tag url one 18, second 22, third, 5

Comment: Please visit this link bro if you creat this this is not impossible for you server1.yt-api.com/vimotube.php?id=5lf9GWCQcMA please visit only change tag url one 18, second 22, third, 5

Comment: How to i show 3 different redirect link in this file on one id i have this link with 3 itag ids low itag-5, medium-18, HD-22 look like these `http://ytapi.com/api/'.$id.'/direct/5/`, `http://ytapi.com/api/'.$id.'/direct/18/,` `http://ytapi.com/api/'.$id.'/direct/22/` these link different redirects with quality how to i show on this file 3 redirections like this visit `http://server1.yt-api.com/vimotube.php?id=5lf9GWCQcMA` please dear solve this last request @hassan

Comment: How to i show 3 different redirect link in this file on one id i have this link with 3 itag ids low itag-5, medium-18, HD-22 look like these `http://ytapi.com/api/'.$id.'/direct/5/`, `http://ytapi.com/api/'.$id.'/direct/18`/, `http://ytapi.com/api/'.$id.'/direct/22/` these link different redirects with quality how to i show on this file 3 redirections like this visit `http://server1.yt-api.com/vimotube.php?id=5lf9GWCQcMA` please dear solve this last request @hassan

Comment: @SyedAliRazaNaqvi please open new question.

Answer (score 0):

`header` is a function, you do not need the `$`. Just use `header('Location: http://ytapi.com/api/'.$id.'/direct/18/');`

You were also missing a single dot after `$id`.

Comment: but this is not work this code redirect this link cant show code of redirect

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to fetch the page contents. You need to submit the URL in this case instead of a redirect (I removed the `die()` in between, it will abort your execution): `$url='http://ytapi.com/api/'.$id.'/direct/18/'); $ch = curl_init($url);`

Comment: Great work sir please tell 1 more this code access one redirect code but i need final destination of code please tell me how can i access final distination please visit this link and check this link goes doc.google.com but i access at this time http://r13---sn-vgqs7n7d.de2.ytapi.com/videoplayback?

Comment: Please check this link where redirect http://ytapi.com/api/5lf9GWCQcMA/direct/18/ this link redirect on docs.google.com please tell me what i'm change for get final destination of url with these codes

Comment: This code work fine for first redirection i need final destination